# Scroll view page control image is not fitting exactly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have a view above that i am having scroll view m adding image to scroll view as sub view it is not fitting exactly to width and height

following this  https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tapagecontrol
by adding autolayout m getting problem bcz this is not autolayout

```
- (void)setupScrollViewImages
{
    for (UIScrollView *scrollView in self.scrollViews) {
        [self.imagesData enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *imageName, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.frame) * idx, 0, CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(scrollView.frame))];
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
            [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have more than one scroll view?

Comment: i m having one scroll view

Comment: then why do you iterate over `self.scrollViews`? is it an array containing only one scroll view?

Comment: try this code UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"banner.png"];
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake (0,0,self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.frame.size;
self.scrollView.bounces = NO;

Comment: ya for test i was using three scroll views i will edit my question i m having only one scroll view

Comment: try code i will post in comment

Comment: i tried this no effect

Comment: i  have added link u can check it

Comment: Same problem here, can't make center alignment. Any solution ? :-)

Comment: @salman4siddiquistackoverflow Did you get your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think below line can probably solve your problem

```
imgV.clipsToBounds=YES;
```

I am using below code and its working exactly fine

```
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    // create imageView
    AsyncImageView *imgV = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*topScrollView.frame.size.width, 0, topScrollView.frame.size.width, topScrollView.frame.size.height)];
    // set scale to fill
    imgV.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    imgV.clipsToBounds=YES;
    [[Model sharedInstance] setImageWithUrl:[imgArray objectAtIndex:i] forAsyncImageView:imgV];
    // apply tag to access in future
    imgV.tag=i+100;
    // add to scrollView
    [topScrollView addSubview:imgV];
}
```

Comment: no effect my image is getting extended by width and little height when i scroll

Comment: i have added link u can check it

Answer (score 0):

You can force the `imageview` to have the same size before adding to the `scrollview`.

```
CGSize size = scrollView.frame.size;
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
```

Comment: same m getting if i give autolayout  leading edge from right it is comming correct from left it is giving problem

Comment: i have added link u can check it

Answer (score 0):

Try like below,

Your view hierarchy should be like :

`ScrollView` - `UIView` - `YourImageview`

Don't add imageview directly on scrollview add one view between.

Second thing set your imageview's content mode `UIViewContentModeScaletoFill`

Hope this will help :)

Comment: can u plz check the link in qns in that it in coming when i use autolayout its giving problem

Comment: enable to understand what you trying to say. link in your question is third party library. so it doesn't make sense to visit it. what's you need exactly ?

Comment: if u check image scroll in that 3rd party is comming end to end images but if u use size class and autolayout image width is getting extended end to end

Comment: if u want implement and check it

Comment: what you want exactly ?

Comment: image should fit exactly within screen it is getting stretched

Comment: Check your constraints. you probably set wrong constraints i think.

Comment: First try it u will cm to knw

Comment: If there is problem with library then why are you using it? you should not use this library which is not allow autolayout.

Comment: m not using that library i m implementing that idea

Comment: Post your code how you are managing it so that anyone can solve your issue.

Comment: my problem will get solved when u implement that 3rd party with autolayout its only for iphone i want generic layout so plz implement that pod with size class and autolayout